# How to backup postgis database via terminal in linux?

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, postgis, database-backups

I tried to back up a PostGIS database via terminal from the info from the site
https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/backup.html
like this

> pg_dump --file=test_pro.backup --format=c --port=5432 --username=postgres test_pro

but I am encountering an error like this

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT a.attnum, a.attname, a.atttypmod, a.attstattarget, a.attstorage, t.typstorage, a.attnotnull, a.atthasdef, a.attisdropped, a.attlen, a.attalign, a.attislocal, pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid,a.atttypmod) AS atttypname, array_to_string(a.attoptions, ', ') AS attoptions, CASE WHEN a.attcollation <> t.typcollation THEN a.attcollation ELSE 0 END AS attcollation, a.attidentity, pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(option_name) || ' ' || pg_catalog.quote_literal(option_value) FROM pg_catalog.pg_options_to_table(attfdwoptions) ORDER BY option_name), E',
> ') AS attfdwoptions FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid WHERE a.attrelid = '23466'::pg_catalog.oid AND a.attnum > 0::pg_catalog.int2 ORDER BY a.attnum

this is my django database setting

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'test_pro',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'test_pro',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

what can I do to backup the PostGIS database via the terminal in linux

Comment: postgis should be installed.

Comment: its already installed

Comment: Is the same version 2.5 installed?

Comment: Do you get that error during backup or during restore?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes

Comment: Oh, I did the silly thing and asked a logician... What I meant was: which exact command causes the error message?